# push to gerrit change with force or without?

Tags: push, gerrit

There is a change in my gerrit server that I pull and checkout in my local repo like this:

```
git fetch <repoURL> refs/changes/<xx/yyyyyy/z> && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

After that my local repo switches to some detached state commit, in which I want to work the usual way I do with git e.g.:

1. add another commit with the (still lacking in the downloaded gerrit change) change
2. unite those two into one preserving the original commit message (with gerrit Change ID):

   git rebase -i HEAD~2

Now can I just push to gerrit (in order to create a new (next) gerrit patchset) with:

```
3. git push <repoURL> HEAD:refs/for/branch
```

or do I have to push with force:

```
3. git push -f <repoURL> HEAD:refs/for/branch
```

Comment: If you want to move a branch sideways or backwards, not just strictly forward, you always have to use force push. Without force push you're only allowed to move a branch strictly forward. If your rebase changes an existing commit already in the remote, and on the branch in the remote, you will need to force push to accept the new location of the branch.

Comment: I kind of new this from git POV, but when one pushes a change to gerrit, that is not pure git, and the push is done to HEAD:refs/for/master, so if there is already commits in HEAD:refs/for/master for that particular change, I guess I should first "pull --rebase" on some particular git reference, that corresponds to the gerrit change that is open. Otherwise the "push -f" after "git rebase -i HEAD~2" may destroy the ongoing gerrit review for the given change...

Comment: Probably, the idea of gerrit is "one git commit for one gerrit-patchset". Then the "one git commit for the whole change" is a wrong approach here...

Comment: The answer to this question is purely a Gerrit issue; from the Git side all we can say is what @LasseV.Karlsen already mentioned. I have not actually used Gerrit but my understanding of how it works is that you must get a Gerrit change-ID assigned; after that, you always use the change-ID, and force-push if needed, using the change-ID in all your commit messages so that the Gerrit server can fish them out of the `refs/for/branch` commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what is the state of the change you have fetched? Is it "open" (not merged) or "closed" (merged)?

If it's merged, you don't need to download the change using the fetch/checkout commands, you should just fetch your repository and get the change in the branch (since it is already integrated).

If it's not merged, what do you want to do? Do you want to fix the change or do you want to make another change based on this change?

I suppose by your text that you want to fix the change (since you intend to join the changes), then the correct way to do is the following:

1- Download the change:

```
git fetch <repoURL> refs/changes/<xx/yyyyyy/z> && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

2- Make your change

3- Amend the commit (keeping the same Change-Id)

```
git commit --amend
```

4- Push the amended commit

```
git push <repoURL> HEAD:refs/for/branch
```

Comment: Yep. Take-away message: forced push ("-f") is not needed when pushing to Gerrit's HEAD:refs/for/branch even though the local branch's commit history was rewritten after rebase/amend.

Comment: Exact, this is the way to fix change issues found in the review process.