# How to push in Gerrit without creating new commit

Tags: git, gerrit

Hello well my problem is after I make some modifications in the code I push it to the Gerrit repo.
Let's say that I made a new modifcation or fixed a typo. I want to know how to push my code again in the same commit without making a new one.

so this is how push my commit the first time

```
git add .
git commit -m "whatever"
push ssh://username@gerrit.bk.com:29418/val/Test_Gerrit HEAD:refs/for/master
```

now after an other modification this how i try to amend

```
git add .
git commit --amend
push ssh://username@gerrit.bk.com:29418/val/Test_Gerrit HEAD:refs/for/master
```

but it always creates a new commit in Gerrit . how can i modify and push my code without creating a new commit please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but it always creates a new commit in Gerrit

That is indeed the expected result, as illustrated in "[push to Gerrit change with force or without?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69376273/6309)":

> Take-away message: forced push ("`-f`") is *not* needed when pushing to Gerrit's `HEAD:refs/for/branch` even though the local branch's commit history was rewritten after rebase/amend.

But: that created a new commit, if the Change-Id is missing or different.

As the [Gerrit documentation mentions](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-changeid.html#change-upload):

> If a matching review is found, Gerrit will add the new commit as a new patch set on the existing change.

---

The [OP Louay Gourrida](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10647190/louay-gourrida) reports:

> The problem was that the commits are being created *without* a Change-Id (the Change-Id is auto generated) so when you make a change in the commit and push again, Gerrit does not recognize the commit cause because there is no Change-Id.
> Therefore it creates a new commit that is also without a Change-Id.
>
> I had to add a file called `commit-msg` in `/.git/hooks` in my local that auto generate `Change-Id` for each commit.

This is the [commit-msg Hook](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-hook-commit-msg.html):

> A Git hook automatically invoked by `git commit`, and most other commit creation tools such as git citool or git gui.
>
> The Gerrit Code Review supplied implementation of this hook is a short shell script which automatically inserts a globally unique `Change-Id` tag in the footer of a commit message.
>
> When present, Gerrit uses this tag to track commits across cherry-picks and rebases.

Comment: so what i understand is that if there is a review Gerrit will update the same commit , if thre is no review it will always create a new commit ?

Comment: @LouayGOURRIDA If there is a review, Gerrit will add the new commit as a new patch set on the existing change. But that is still a new commit.

Comment: okey im really sorry but im kinda new to this Gerrit, so im not sure if i got what you said but let explain , https://imgur.com/a/yg6ljvi in this screenshot there is an outgoing review  called "test amendos" my problem is when I do the ```commit --amend``` it always creates a new outgoing review with the same name "test amendos" rather than just update that. if that makes it more clear

Comment: @LouayGOURRIDA From what I understand, it does always create a commit.

Comment: I actaully solved it , the problem was that the commits are beeing created without a Change-Id (the Change-Id is auto generated) so when u make a change in the commit and push again Gerrit doesnt recognize the commit cause because there is no Change-Id therefore it creates a new commit that is also without a Change-Id. I had to add a file called commit-msg in /.git/hooks in my local that auto generate Change-Id for each commit ill add a link from where i got the file in the documentation.

Comment: @LouayGOURRIDA Good catch, well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, and added a link to the `commit-msg` hook documentation.